# fopen returns Resource id #4

Tags: php, facebook, https, fopen

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&access_token=2227470867|2.mLWDqcUsekDYZ_FQQXYnHw__.3600.1279803600-100001317997096|YxS1eGhjx2rpNYLNE9wLrfb5hMc.", "r");
echo $handle;
?>
```

Why does it echo `Resource id #4` instead of the page itself?

Comment: @Raj - Probably because it's such a basic question that didn't need asking if the OP had simply visited the manual pages on php.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns a resource pointer to the file, not the content of the file. It simply opens it for subsequent reading and/or writing, dependent on the mode in which you opened the file.

You need to [fread()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) the data from the resource referenced in $handle.

This is all basic stuff that you could have read for yourself on the manual pages of php.net

Answer (score 6):

Once you have created your $handle you now need to fread() the contents.

```
$contents = ''; 
while (!feof($handle)) 
{ 
$contents .= fread($handle, 8192); 
} 
fclose($handle); 
echo $contents;
```

source: php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&access_token=2227470867|2.mLWDqcUsekDYZ_FQQXYnHw__.3600.1279803600-100001317997096|YxS1eGhjx2rpNYLNE9wLrfb5hMc.", "r");
    echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because fopen return the resource handle of the file it opened not the contents.